# symfony2 command gets terminated without any error

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I've developed a symfony2 command to export data from the database to a file.xml.

It's absolutely not a timeout matter because I set it to 30 minutes `set_time_limit(1800);`

In my local machine it works well. I know that this command isn't perfect because it takes too long before it exports (about 15minutes) and it uses a lot of memory about 800 Megabytes.

The problem I've been having is that in the production server the command gets terminated with no error.

What's going on?

**UPDATE1**

My project is running on php5.3.2 and in /etc/php/cli/php.ini I have `memory_limit = -1`

**UPDATE2**

Actually the message returned is `Process stopped`

**UPDATE3**

I just figured out the problem, actually it stops because there are no more bytes left in the RAM.

Comment: Are you sure that all configuration settings are set the right way on the server?

Comment: The two important parameters in php.ini are set the right way, please have a look at my update1 + set_time_limit(1800) is at the begining of my symfony2 command file. What else should I look at?

Comment: Have you set `memory_limit = -1` in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` as well?

Comment: There is no fpm directory under /etc/php5/ (apache2, cli and conf.d)

Comment: That's normal for fpm. Update cli. Also look into [these tips](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

Comment: Actually I cannot update my php because there are a lot of dependencies. php.ini in cli is modified (limit of time and limit of memory). Otherwise I'm running the command through the crontab and I'm not interested in the process component of symfony (for now )

Comment: Enable display errors on your script. <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: It doesn't change anything in the output/logs. However I'm certain that it's because when the ram is fully used and the swapping has reached its maximum, the system stops the script. (I need confirmation for that though :) )